# how to append list model by using c++ vector

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am new to Qt and QML.

I am now trying to get a list from c++ code and apply the list to list model so that listview can show the updated list.

What I did so far is to build listview and listmodel and delegator as follows:

```
Rectangle {
id: container
width: 500; height: 400

function getModel()
{
    return environmentModel
}

ListModel {
     id: environmentModel

     ListElement {
         hs: 2
         tp: 2.45
         dp: 2.45
     }
     ListElement {
         hs: 1
         tp: 2.45
         dp: 2.45
     }
     ListElement {
         hs: 3
         tp: 2.45
         dp: 2.45
     }
 }

Component {
    id: environmentDelegate
    Row {
        spacing: 10
        Text { width: 100; text: hs }
        Text { width: 100; text: tp }
        Text { width: 100; text: dp }
    }
}

Component {
    id: environmentHeader
    Row {
        spacing: 10
        Text { width: 100; text: "Hs" }
        Text { width: 100; text: "Tp" }
        Text { width: 100; text: "Dp" }
    }
}
// The delegate for each location in the model:

ListView {
         anchors.fill: parent
         model: environmentModel
         delegate: environmentDelegate
         header: environmentHeader
     }
}
```

What I want to do is

1) I have a c++ function which returns a vector, say

```
 class Record {
    int date;
    char time;
    float hs;
    float tp;
    float dp;
 };
 std::vector<Record> getRecords();
```

2) If a button is clicked, the list returned from the above function getRecords() is appended to the listmodel. I studied a little bit Qt and QML, signal and slot but still don't get any idea. It would be great if someone make an example.

Comment: You can use any data source for a mode, you just have to implement a `QAbstractListModel` wrapper around it.

Answer (score 0):

There are good examples for creating models [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html).

I would create a c++ method to append to your model and declare it Q_INVOKABLE. You call the method using the mouse press signal (see "exposing methods" on [this page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html)).